# Read paths in .properties file

Tags: java, properties, path

I'm trying to put all my urls & paths in .properties file. So that if I'm going to change them it would be easier. So here's my path.properties (it's in src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\path.properties):

```
path.clientIdentify=C:\\Palms\\client-identify-bin\\dll
path.clientEnroll=C:\\Palms\\client-enroll-bin\\dll
path.pvInfoIni=C://Palms//PV//PVInfo.ini
path.pvEnrollIni=C://Palms//PV//PVEnroll.ini
```

And I was trying to call the paths in my controller, so this is what I did:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/call")
public class PalmsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/palmsIdentify")
    public ResponseEntity<String> palmusIdentify() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties")) {
            properties.load(is);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "StartSample.bat");
        builder.directory(new File("path.clientIdentify"));
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        r.close();
        process.waitFor();

        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            p.load(new FileInputStream("path.pvInfoIni"));
            String pvidNO1 = p.getProperty("PVIDNO");
            String pvidNo2 = p.getProperty("PVIDNo");
            String authentication = p.getProperty("Authentication");

            // Convert to JSON
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("pvId", pvidNO1);
            jsonObject.put("PVIDNo", pvidNo2);
            jsonObject.put("is_Authenticated", authentication);

            return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(),headers ,HttpStatus.OK);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":" + e.getMessage() + "\"}", headers,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/palmusEnroll")
    public ResponseEntity<String> palmusEnroll() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties")) {
            properties.load(is);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "StartSample.bat");
        builder.directory(new File("path.clientEnroll"));
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        r.close();
        process.waitFor();

        // PARSING
        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            p.load(new FileInputStream("path.pvEnrollIni"));
            String pvidNO1 = p.getProperty("PVIDNO");
            String palmusId = p.getProperty("PALMUS_ID");


            // Convert to JSON
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("pvId", pvidNO1);
            jsonObject.put("palmusId", palmusId);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(),headers ,HttpStatus.OK);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":" + e.getMessage() + "\"}", headers,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

    }

}
```

But it seems like it doesn't call the paths. Or maybe I'm not doing it right? Sorry newbie here, I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the value from the properties file. If the properties object is loaded, you can get the value from the properties file by `properties.getProperty("key")`.

---

Load the resource properties file using the following snippet:

```
  properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/spring/path.properties"));
```

And it should replace:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties")) {
    properties.load(is);
}
```

And then you can get the paths like this:

```
properties.getProperty("path.clientIdentify");
```

Comment: Could you debug if your code is even loading the properties file?

Comment: I got the error resource not found. So it does not load the properties file. Why is that?

Comment: @KendallH. modiffied my answer to load the correct file.

Comment: This is what I did Sir: http://pastie.org/private/re2kciupvhnlwpxyqycgea but it still don't work.

Comment: @KendallH. you haven't tried a thing like I suggested.